# проблема с обраоткой вывода на экран

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax, json

Есть скрипт по отдельность выводит все нормально

```
WHERE users.id=:id_1');
$result->execute(array(':id_1' => $id_1));
```

но вместе никак ничего не пишет

```
WHERE users.id=:id_1 OR users.id=:id_2');
$result->execute(array(':id_1' => $id_1, ':id_2' => $id_2));
```

ниже пример кода хочу сделать сравнение объявлений

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$idd = $_POST['id'];
$result = count($idd);
$id = array();
if (count($result) == 1)
{
   $id_1 = (current($idd));
}
if (count($result) < 3)
{
   next($idd);
   $id_2 = (current($idd));
}
if (count($result) < 4)
{
   next($idd);
   $id_3 = (current($idd));
}

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bd.php');
$result = $pdo->prepare(
  'SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.kl, users.Name, users.sebe, images_ava.catalog_small, images_ava.filename_small FROM users INNER JOIN images_ava ON users.id = images_ava.id WHERE users.id=:id_1 OR users.id=:id_2');
$result->execute(array(':id_1' => $id_1, ':id_2' => $id_2));
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
  $myrow = $result-> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  do {
    $file = explode(',', $myrow['filename_small']);
    foreach ($file as $val) {
       ;
        echo json_encode("
            <div class='row'> 
             <div class='col-md-10 block-info width'>
               <div class='col-md-3'> <img src='registration/1/".$myrow['catalog_small'].$val."' class='img-responsive' title='1' alt='1' />
               <div class='col-md-3'> ".$myrow['kl']."</div>
             </div>
            ");
    }
  }
  while ($myrow = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY));
}
else
{
  // Собщение о пустой таблице
  print_r ("<p>Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена, в таблице нет записей.</p>");
  exit();
}
```

и так через аякс вызываю его

```js
$(window).load(function() { //говорим скрипту что он сработает когда вся страница загрузится
  var ID = [];//обозначаем переменную для массива
  $('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function() {//ловим клик
    ID.push($(this).data('id'));//записываем результат кликов в массив
    console.log(ID);
  });//что выдадет консоль точнее масив
    $('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $("#basket").show("slow"); // показываем как откроется форма
  });
  // показываем как откроется форма
  $('.compare_basket').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $(".compare_basket").hide("slow");

    });// показываем как откроется форма
  $('#basket').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $(".compare_basket").show("slow");
    
    console.log(ID); //что выдадет консоль
    $.ajax({ // сам ajax запрос
    url: "myscript.php", // обработчик на php 
    data: {id: ID}, // даные которые передатся
    type: "POST", // метод
    success: function(response){
     $("#ajaxDivId_1").html(response); 
     }, // если запрос удачный выводим то что вернул скрипт php
    error: function(er){ alert(er); }, // если запрос не удался выводим ошибку
  })
      .done(function(data) { //отладочный запрос по которому заносятся данные 
       // выводим отладочную информацию

      });


  });
})
```

Comment: Ну если ваш js код сообщает вам что в php ошибка, может быть стоит посмотреть что же там за ошибка все таки?

Answer (score 1):

Предположу что проблема у вас в вашем цикле `do{}while()`, перед циклом в переменную  `$myrow` кладете массив (`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`), работаете с переменной как с массивом, затем, условие кладет туда обьект, и работает с ним как с массивом, есть подозрение что скрипту не нравится.

Для чего вы используете `do{}while()` не знаю, но возможно проще использовать `while(){}`:

```
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
    while (($myrow = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
        $file = explode(',', $myrow['filename_small']);
        foreach ($file as $val) {
            echo json_encode("
            <div class='row'> 
                <div class='col-md-10 block-info width'>
                    <div class='col-md-3'> <img src='registration/1/".$myrow['catalog_small'].$val."' class='img-responsive' title='1' alt='1' />
                <div class='col-md-3'> ".$myrow['kl']."</div>
            </div>
            ");
        }
    }
}
```

Так же у вас после `foreach ($file as $val) {` загадочная точка с запятой - `;`, возможно здесь опечатка, но быть там ее не должно.

Answer (score 0):

а пробовал использовать bindParam() и/или bindValue()? (юзай квадратные скобки массива)
Хотя и так должно сработать (как у тебя)
но все равно попробуй))

Comment: сори выводит вот это если два доавляю error: function(er){ alert(er); } что запрос не проходит

Comment: Добавь метку темы json и JavaScript (сейчас народ шарящий по JS подтянется)